# SQL Distinct but not so distinct query

Tags: sql, select, distinct

Maybe I'm over-complicating this ...

I just need a "simple" query to select one column but return only distinct rows. 
Here's the key, they need to be ruled out if they are similar, not just match exactly.

For example, here's my current query

```
select distinct channel from audio_srcs order by channel
```

The trick is this returns something like the following

```
Channel
--------
1001
1003
1003 <Description@unitid>
1004
1004 <Description@unitid>
```

I want the only one of the 1003 rows to show up and one of the 1004 rows (for example). I don't care which one it returns.

My desired end result would look like this:

```
Channel
---------
1001
1003
1004
etc.
```

Comment: What criteria is used to determine if two values are similar? In your example, rows are considered similar if the first for characters match. Is that always the case, or is the criteria something like "all the characters from the beginning of the string to the first space match", or something else?

Comment: You need to add more rules to how you choose the values. Are they always a number first followed possibly by a description?

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT distinct left(Channel, 4) as Channel  --  or maybe first 5 characters
 from audio_srcs
 order by channel
```

Comment: You're jumping the gun here... the OP hasn't specified what he means by _similar_, so your guess that he means the first 4-5 characters is premature. What if it's "equal up to the first non-digit or end of string?".

Comment: Quite possibly. SO doesn't really support the back-and-forth of proper requirements definitions (aka resolving the "what-ifs"). I  generally respond to posts based on my best interpretation/guess of the requirements presented, then hang back and wait for any "no, wait, that's not what I really wanted" feedback.

Answer (score 3):

I would take the separator as the distinction.  You just want the first token in the column:

```
SELECT distinct left(Channel,
                     (case when charindex(' ', channel) <= 0 then len(channel)
                           else charindex(' ', channel)
                      end
                     )
                    ) as Channel  --  or maybe first 5 characters
from audio_srcs
order by channel
```

I've used the SQL Server version of the string functions.